# How to pass uid as a parameter in firebase? React+Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: auth response]I am using react and have logged in user using firebase auth and storing the uid app context.

```
Security rules:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if
          request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to keep this security rules.
I want to make request with uid. How do i do that?
This way gives error.

```
await db.collection('users').doc(uuid).set({name:name});
```

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

How do i pass uid as parameter to each request while writing to the database?

Comment: The SDK does all auth related work for you. IT seems like you are not logged in using Firebase Auth currently and hence the error. Can you confirm you have logged in ?

Comment: updated with  login response

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you initialize `uuid` right now, but it should be:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    var uuid = user.uid;
    await db.collection('users').doc(uuid).set({name:name});
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

This snippet comes pretty directly from the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).